# Math/Trig to get XYZ coordinates of dipping ellipse in C#

Tags: c#, trigonometry, ellipse

I need to get the coordinates of points along an ellipse that lies on a dipping plane.  The ellipse is also rotated in the XY plane.  I am able to get correct X and Y coordinates of points along a rotated horizontal ellipse, and the X and Y points of the horizontal projection of a dipping ellipse, but cannot figure out the maths/trig that I need to get the Z value of the points on the dipping ellipse.  I am trying to do this by using the apparent dip of a vector from the center of the ellipse to each point along the dipping ellipse.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
class ellipsoid
{
    public ellipsoid() { }
    public double bearing { get; set; }
    public double plunge { get; set; }
    public double dip { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
}

class exampleCalc
{
    public void createDippingEllipse(ellipsoid ellipsoid, double majorAxis, double semiMajorAxis)
    // majorAxis is the longest axis, semiMajorAxis is the shorter axis
    {

        double semiMajorAxisApparent = 0;
        Int32 strNum = 1;
        point delta = new point();
        point horz = new point();
        point ep = new point();
        point p = new point();
        p.x = ellipsoid.x;
        p.y = ellipsoid.y;
        p.z = ellipsoid.z;
        // az represents the angular interval along which points will be located
        for (Int32 az = 0; az <= 360; az = az + 10)
        {
            double rakeAngle = 0;
            if (az >= 0 && az <= 90)
            {
                rakeAngle = az;
            }
            if (az > 90 && az <= 180)
            {
                rakeAngle = 180 - az;
            }
            if (az > 180 && az <= 270)
            {
                rakeAngle = az - 180;
            }
            if (az > 270 && az <= 360)
            {
                rakeAngle = 360 - az;
            }

            if (ellipsoid.dip == 90)
            {
                semiMajorAxisApparent = semiMajorAxis;
            }
            else
            {
                semiMajorAxisApparent = semiMajorAxis * Math.Cos(ep.degreesToRadians(Math.Abs(ellipsoid.dip)));
            }
            double cosAz = Math.Cos(ep.degreesToRadians(az));
            double sinAz = Math.Sin(ep.degreesToRadians(az));
            // convert mathematical bearing to bearing where north is zero
            double bearing0north = ellipsoid.bearing + 90;

            if (bearing0north > 360) { bearing0north = 360 - bearing0north; }

            double cosBearing = Math.Cos(ep.degreesToRadians(bearing0north));
            double sinBearing = Math.Sin(ep.degreesToRadians(bearing0north));
            // delta.x and delta.y are correct
            delta.x = (majorAxis * cosBearing * cosAz) - (semiMajorAxisApparent * sinBearing * sinAz);
            delta.y = (majorAxis * cosAz * sinBearing) + (semiMajorAxisApparent * sinAz * cosBearing);
            double horzDist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(delta.x, 2) + Math.Pow(delta.y, 2));
            // uncorrected for apparent horz length
            horz.x = (majorAxis * cosBearing * cosAz) - (semiMajorAxis * sinBearing * sinAz);
            horz.y = (majorAxis * cosAz * sinBearing) + (semiMajorAxis * sinAz * cosBearing);

            double apparentDip = Math.Atan(Math.Tan(ep.degreesToRadians(Math.Abs(ellipsoid.bearing))) * Math.Sin(ep.degreesToRadians(rakeAngle)));
            // delta.z is not correct
            delta.z = horzDist * Math.Atan(apparentDip);

            ep.x = p.x + delta.x;
            ep.y = p.y + delta.y;
            ep.z = p.z + delta.z;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are truly attempting the most complex possible solution to a relatively straightforward problem (except perhaps choosing a non-inertial frame).

Simply solve all the maths in an ellipse lying in the X-Y plane, about the origin, and calculate the affine matrix that translates and rotates the ellipse to the desired location and orientation. Then simply apply the matrix to each calculated point to get the correct oriented point.

Comment: Hi Pieter - Thanks for the reply.  I'm not familiar with affine matricies (although I will go and do some research on it now).  Would you be willing to share a bit of code that I could use as an example?

Comment: My Hexgrid Utilities for Games is Open Source - use as you wish provided you credit me as original author: http://hexgridutilities.codeplex.com/. Although only 2D, the classes IntMatrix2D and IntVector2D may help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, Pieter - I'll have a look at it.